# How to serialize apache arrow c++ table, trans through socket,and deserialize it at python side

Tags: python, c++, apache-arrow

I'm new to apache arrow, My C++ project use apache::table to store data well.
and now, I need to trans c++ table with socket to other python client. why try this,because python client needs to tans data to dataframe and I notice that arrow table in python can use 'to_pandas()' to do that.
I tried to look up arrow cython code,but I found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* send an arrow table over a basic socket (example below) but you're probably better off using Flight.  Flight uses grpc to send arrow data back and forth and it will remove some of the tedium of using sockets.  [Here](https://mirai-solutions.ch/news/2020/06/11/apache-arrow-flight-tutorial/) is a great example.

The complete socket example can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/westonpace/f5657117d7121b84c1356adec350fdb2).

I will put the relevant bits here:

#### Sending

```
void SendTable(int socket_fd) {
  auto output_res = SocketOutputStream::Open(socket_fd);
  if (!CheckErr(output_res.status(), "arrow::io::FileOutputStream")) {
    return;
  }
  auto output = *output_res;

  arrow::MemoryPool *pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();

  auto table = MakeTable();
  if (table == nullptr) {
    return;
  }

  auto writer_res = arrow::ipc::MakeStreamWriter(output, table->schema());
  if (!CheckErr(writer_res.status(), "arrow::ipc::MakeStreamWriter")) {
    return;
  }
  auto writer = *writer_res;
  if (!CheckErr(writer->WriteTable(*table), "RecordBatchWriter::WriteTable")) {
    return;
  }
  CheckErr(writer->Close(), "RecordBatchWriter::Close");
}
```

#### Receiving

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.bind((listen, port))
    sock.listen()
    print(f"Listening on {listen} on port {port}")
    conn, _ = sock.accept()
    with conn:
        conn_file = conn.makefile(mode="b")
        reader = pyarrow.ipc.RecordBatchStreamReader(conn_file)
        table = reader.read_all()
        print(table)
        print(table.to_pandas())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. and I tried to use it in my project, and it's useful.

Comment: By the way,   In C++, I want to trans several tables with diferent headers, but at python, 'reader.read_all()' function reads all tables one time.  what could i do to read them one by one?

Comment: If the headers are different you will need to create a reader/writer for each table.  If the headers were the same you can send it as multiple record batches on the same reader/writer.

Comment: In different headers condition, can I create different reader/writer with the same socket? I tried to make different writers in C++ with the same socket, but in python, how to make different readers with the same socket to receive bathce streams